# When div reaches bottom of window, stick and scroll over next div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create this sliding scroll behavior in between divs. Let's say that the markup looks like this:

```
<main>
   <div class="slide">Content</div>
   <div class="slide">Content</div>
   <div class="slide">Content</div>
</main>
```

Every `.slide` div would have different heights depending on the content inside them and would of course also change it's height depending on window size.

What I want is that when each div reaches it's bottom when scrolling the page, I. e. when the bottom of the div is at the bottom of the window, the div should become fixed and the div underneath should then scroll over the previous fixed div. And this behavior would be repeated for each div within the container (in this example `main`).

Do you have any ideas for how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I figured that adding the following to each section through JavaScript (in my case jQuery just for this exercise) will make each div behave like I wanted on scroll:

```
$(".slide").each(function(){
    $(this).css({
        "top": `-${$(this).height() - $(window).height()}px`
    })
})
```

Essentially applying a CSS `top` value that is the div height minus the window height.

This would also require the divs to have `position: sticky` applied to them through CSS.